# Vaadin 23 how to add multilanguage meta description to the page

Tags: vaadin, meta-tags, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I know how to add meta page title in Vaadin 23 - I use `HasDynamicTitle` and thus can provide different titles at different languages (depends on the user locale) for different pages. But how to do the same meta `description`? I need to be able to provide different meta tags for different pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see there is no convenience API for dynamically changing the meta description. Looking at how `HasDynamicTitle` is implemented, we can see that it effectively delegates to [`UiInternals.setTitle`](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/09c3fa8bc2dcbcbcab0b1574208250d9ecf5dbff/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/internal/UIInternals.java#L600-L619), which just schedules a Javascript call of `document.title = $0`.

If you want to do the same for the meta description, you can schedule a JS call during the initialization of your view to modify the content of the meta tag:

```java
this.executeJs(
  "document.querySelector('meta[name=\"description\"]').setAttribute('content', $0);",
  getLocalizedDescription()
);
```

Note that this only modifies the meta description after the page has loaded, and does not affect the content of the meta tag that is in the initial HTML document. If you want to modify that, let's say for SEO purposes or generating link previews, then you need to look into using [`IndexHtmlRequestListener`](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/modifying-the-bootstrap-page/#IndexHtmlRequestListener-interface). The same would apply for the title, the method you are using at the moment only changes the title after loading the page.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. In case of SEO purpose, I'm just wondering if there are some additional tools already exist which may abstract us from such a boilerplate work with help of `IndexHtmlRequestListener`? Such tool/library for example may automatically generate HTML preview and cache it somewhere?

Comment: Personally not aware of SEO solutions, though they might exist. Maybe someone with more experience in developing Vaadin apps can recommend something.